# How to append content in .txt file in new line

Tags: php

Hi i have a php file using that php file  i am inserting data into .txt file i am using append  now i want to append  new data in next line it data should not be append in same line

my php file given below Here

**demo.php**

```
<?php
 $myfile="sentsms/".date('m-d-Y').'.txt';
file_put_contents($myfile, $message,"\n".FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

How can i achieve my desired output

Any help will be appreciated

Thanku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"\n"` belongs at the end of the string you wish to append to.

```
$message = "The message..." . "\n";
$myfile="sentsms/".date('m-d-Y').'.txt';
file_put_contents($myfile, $message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

`09-22-2014.txt` file

reloaded 3 times output:

```
The message...
The message...
The message...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: \r\n

```
file_put_contents($myfile, $message,"\r\n".FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Or

```
$message = "Your text\r\n";
file_put_contents($myfile, $message, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Test new option, use double quotes if not, skip line @satyamsharma

Comment: message string is not fix it is dyanamic

Comment: file_put_contents($myfile, ($message . "\r\n"), FILE_APPEND);

Comment: Some file types means that \n is to jump online and other \r you then just add 2 to the end of your message @satyamsharma